# What is the meaning of "ant maven-setup" in Roboelectic Maven Build?

Tags: android, maven, ant, robolectric

I am trying to use [RobolectricSample application](https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample) for unit testing Android application. 
In the instruction for installation of application with Maven the first step is

`ant maven-setup`. I could not understand why is this command required and what it will do?

Any explanation will be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Ant build file [build.xml](https://github.com/pivotal/RobolectricSample/blob/master/build.xml#L147), `ant maven-setup` does two things:

- **maven-install-jars:**

  Install 2 required jar libraries (guice-2.0-no_aop.jar & maps.jar) into Maven local repository.
- **maven-set-android-sdk:**

  Reset Android SDK path in pom.xml iff <path> is defined in android-maven-plugin.

This is not a elegant solution, ideally all those tasks should be handled purely by Maven. However, as this project provide both Ant and Maven build, it reuse the script from Ant in Maven build lifecycle for convenience.

Comment: +1, do I have to install Apache Ant to run this on Windows Command line?